# How to apply a filter to update element in array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a *PHP application* that lets me uploading data to a *MongoDB collection*. For that I have "installed" the PHP driver with no problems.

However, I cannot find anyway -[neither in the PHP guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php)- how could I update an element in an array of arrays.

[Collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8GsO.jpg)

As you may see, *_unidades* is an array of arrays. Each of those arrays contains an ID, a string and another array. In my case, which will be chosen depends on previous param -it has to match with element 1 of one of them.

Once I have selected that structure, I want to insert a new array into its array of arrays (position 2).

Regarding code, I tried the following:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$bulk->update(
    [
        '_isbn' => (int) $_POST["isbn"],
        '_topics' => [
            '0' => (int) $_POST["topic"]
        ]
    ],
    [
        '$set' => [
            '1' => array($_POST["sentence"], $_POST["question"])
        ]
    ]
);        
    
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 100);
$resultado = $manager->executeBulkWrite('libreee.faq', $bulk, $writeConcern);
```

However as you can see I am not capable to determine at least that it doesn't have to be an specific array (7th line).

Comment: Do you perhaps have a possibility/way to format your output into PHP differently? It's usually easier than to mess around with weird array structures.

Comment: Hello @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES, by means of PHP Driver, the only way is based on what this link explains: http://php.net/manual/es/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php.

Comment: I have been looking for a way based on editing an object that after that would have been re-submitted, but impossible...

Comment: Anyway if somebody knew a different way to do that... I'd be very thankful @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES

Comment: You should never put $_POST[""] values directly into a database anyway, this is generally bad practice (although it might be fine in your app, I don't know its structure). You should always first verify that the variable exists e.g. with isset() and/or !empty()  and you would also validate it that it doesn't contain something that could break/mess your database.

I would suggest assigning those variables first and then adding them to the array.

Comment: I will follow this advice -however I do use sometimes isset(), @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES

Comment: Let me know on your progress. once you got that, I'll show you how to pass variables into arrays in a manageable way.

Comment: Yes, as soon as somebody gives me a clue or I find out sth, I'll inform you, @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES

Comment: What are you currently stuck on? I'm here to help :) I

Comment: Look at that collection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8GsO.jpg. I want to iterate somehow and get the array of _unidades__ whose position 1 match certain value. In its position 2 I want to add a new array, @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES

Comment: The doubt is not about creating the array in PHP, but in tracking positions of arrays of arrays in PHP -by MongoDB Driver.

Comment: The screenshotted output looks like some JavaScript output. It's actually quite a lot easier to grab that stuff while it's in JS than it is once you get to PHP (JS has more functions out of the box). In any case, I'll cook something up for you in a bit.

Comment: It's written in BSON, based in JSON. By the way, I look forward to seeing what you are preparing, @I_ATE_YOUR_WORK_FILES. Thanks a lot.